# HTML 5 showing incorrect values

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-canvas, css3pie

I am creating a pie chart to show my skills proficiency on my personal website with the following code -

```
<!-- main skill No. 1 -->
    <div class="skill col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="chart center" data-percent="75">
            <span><span id="chart_num_1"></span> %</span>
        </div>
        <h2>Product Management</h2>
    </div>

<!-- main skill No. 2 -->
    <div class="skill col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="chart center" data-percent="70">
            <span><span id="chart_num_2">70</span> %</span>
        </div>
        <h2>Data Analysis</h2>
    </div>

<!-- main skill No. 3 -->
    <div class="skill col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="chart center" data-percent="65">
            <span><span id="chart_num_3">65</span> %</span>
        </div>
        <h2>Python</h2>
    </div>

<!-- main skill No. 4 -->
    <div class="skill col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="chart center" data-percent="60">
            <span><span id="chart_num_4">60</span> %</span>
        </div>
        <h2>UX/UI</h2>
    </div>
```

However percentages reflecting on the screen are totally different. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: A percentage seems like a strange way to represent a level of proficiency. How can you be 30% skilled at something like data analysis? It is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The number on the charts comes from `js/plugins.js` file.

```
$("#chart_num_1").animateNumber({ number: 55 }, 1500);         
$("#chart_num_2").animateNumber({ number: 30 }, 1500);         
$("#chart_num_3").animateNumber({ number: 35 }, 1500);         
$("#chart_num_4").animateNumber({ number: 60 }, 1500);
```

change the values there to be the same as the `data-percent` of the chart

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was new to web development and was really scratching my head over this!

Comment: @PriyankaNaik You are welcome :) if it's answer your question, please mark it as the correct answer